# Why does android display wrong vectors after multiple builds

Tags: android, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I have been experiencing this issue for a long time now in different apps. I have vector drawables assigned to my `ImageView`. At first install all works fine, each ImageView displays the right drawable but after dozens of builds and runs the app starts misplacing the drawables and showing them in wrong imageviews, the solution to this is to completely uninstall the app then install it. This works during build phase but I always ask my question what will happen when a user receives a dozen updates, wont this happen to them overtime? I am not using `pngs` but `vectors` hence this is not an issue to do with `multiple res folders` and `screen sizes`.

So here is my app after a dozen builds

[image]

And here it is after a clean install

[image]

This is really frustrating when you are working with data on the app you cannot afford to loose, I had to loose my saved addresses just to get the icons to show correctly.
Has anyone had this issue and how did they fix it?

Comment: are you using recyclerview

Comment: @vikaskumar Yes I am, what is it doing?

Comment: if its only two images then it should not be a problem. if its many then recyclerview is trying to recycle the views and some old reference of images are getting used on new ones. you have to clear the old one and again add a new one to make it work.

Comment: @vikaskumar so I need to call `imgView.setImageDrawable(null)`?

Comment: yeah it should work. let me know after trying.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have a select number of `drawables` I ended up just adding a check in my layout like

```
<data>
    <import type="my.app.R"/>
</data>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/round_color_primary"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_margin"
        app:imageResource="@{address.type.value == 120 ? R.drawable.ic_home : (address.type.value == 121 ? R.drawable.ic_work : (address.type.value == 124 ? R.drawable.ic_star : R.drawable.ic_destination_outline))}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/white" />
```